# What's the using equivalent of a function typedef?

Tags: c++, c++11, using-declaration

How can I use the new<sup>1</sup> `using` keyword to declare a function type?

I know how I can use it to declare a function *pointer* type. For example, the following typedef:

```
typedef int (*int_to_int)(int);
```

seems equivalent to the following using declaration:

```
using int_to_int = int (*)(int);
```

How do I do the same for the following non-pointer typedef:

```
typedef int (int_to_intf)(int);
```

My "removing the typedef name and putting it after `using`" algorithm doesn't work:

```
using int_to_intf_u = int ()(int);  // nope, doesn't compile
```

A [goldbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/Z4Q7z6).

---

<sup>1</sup> At least for those poor souls like me who still define "new" as "introduced in C++11".

Comment: Just recall how you use std::function.

Comment: @liliscent - haha, yes exactly. I somehow never made the connection (see my comments on the answer which I wrote before seeing this which you'll have to take my word for since the edit timestamp doesn't prove it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just `int(int)`. To get the abstract declarator, just remove the variable name from an actual declaration. You would declare `int f(int);`, so the abstract declarator should be `int(int)`.

Comment: Interesting, and somehow I implicitly already knew that sytax from `std::function<?>` already. That rule is very simple... so putting it in reverse: can it accommodate the function pointer case?

Comment: @BeeOnRope Yes, because you need the extra parentheses when you declare a function pointer variable.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: to make it a pointer, add a `*` adjacent to the name: `int (*)(int)`

Comment: Thanks all. It's always thought the parens around `(*)` were fundamental, but now I understand it's only needed because of the `*` in the first place.

Comment: Yes it can accommodate the pointer, but then it looks ugly again. personally I'm happy to add a star when I use the new thing, or declare a second using/typedef.